# How to get current system Time Zone by using Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

How to get timezone of the current system by using Lua. (US/Mountain).I am working on Linux os.  I need to know how to get a Linux system like (US/Mountain, Asia/Mumbai). how to write code for that

Answer (score 2):

`print( os.date('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %z',t0))` = `03/25/19 10:57:29 Pacific Daylight Time` I am in Seattle, Washington USA.

The `%z` gives you the timezone, this may be sufficient for your needs, however please note:

> One cannot use os.date("%z") as the format of its return value is non-portable; in particular, Windows systems don't use the C99 semantics for strftime(). - http://lua-users.org/wiki/TimeZone

Alternatively you can do the following to determine the actual value of the offset:

```
local function get_timezone_offset(ts)
    local utcdate   = os.date("!*t", ts)
    local localdate = os.date("*t", ts)
    localdate.isdst = false -- this is the trick
    return os.difftime(os.time(localdate), os.time(utcdate))
end
```

Resources: [lua-users: Time Zone](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TimeZone)

Comment: What is your locale where you get that datetime format?

Comment: Are you referring to the first line of the answer? I state Seattle, i could be more clear an state Seattle, Washington USA.

Comment: I'm surprised you get that date format. I get `Mon Mar 25 15:51:05 2019 -0400`. The `%c` output is locale-dependent. `locale | grep LC_TIME` outputs `LC_TIME=en_CA.utf-8` and `locale date_fmt` outputs `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y` -- what your your outputs?

Comment: @glennjackman `%c` shouldn't be locale-dependent. it is documented as `%c date and time (e.g., 09/16/98 23:48:10)` on https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html

Comment: ah nevermind i see this now: `%x, %X, and %c change according to the locale and the system`

Comment: @glennjackman I am on a windows machine so my date formats short date = `M/d/yyyy` and my time formats long time = `h:mm:ss tt`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the luarocks [`luatz`](https://luarocks.org/modules/daurnimator/luatz) package:

```
$ luarocks install luatz
```

then

```
> luatz = require("luatz")
> now = luatz.time()
> new_york = luatz.time_in('America/New_York', now)
> print(luatz.timetable.new_from_timestamp(new_york))
2019-03-25T16:19:43.696
> paris = luatz.time_in('Europe/Paris', now)
> print(luatz.timetable.new_from_timestamp(paris))
2019-03-25T21:19:43.696
```

That library has limited functions to return information about the time zones themselves:

```
> america_new_york = luatz.get_tz('America/New_York')
> for key,val in pairs(america_new_york:find_current(now)) do print(key,val) end
abbrind 4
isstd   false
isdst   true
isgmt   false
gmtoff  -14400
abbr    EDT
> europe_paris = luatz.get_tz('Europe/Paris')
> for key,val in pairs(europe_paris:find_current(now)) do print(key,val) end
abbrind 17
isstd   true
isdst   false
isgmt   true
gmtoff  3600
abbr    CET
```

---

To query the current system timezone, use `luatz.get_tz()` with no arguments. I don't see any way to get the Olson timezone name, but you can get a few bits of data

```
> now = luatz.time()
> mytz = luatz.get_tz()
> mytz_info = mytz:find_current(now)
> mytz_info.abbr
EDT
> mytz_info.gmtoff
-14400
> mytz_info.isdst
true
```

Comment: Does the library have a function for finding the current system's time zone? did a quick read of the docs and didnt see it but assume i overlooked it... looks like maybe `get_tz()`?

Comment: The time zone *name*, no. The *offset* and abbreviation, yes